# adb -d doesn't find my device but it shows up in adb devices

Tags: android, debugging, adb

I connect through TCP/IP (using adbWireless on Tablet) to my device:

```
$ adb connect 192.168.178.21
connected to 192.168.178.21:5555

$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
192.168.178.21:5555 device

$ adb -d install program.apk
error: device not found
- waiting for device -

$ adb -s 192.168.178.21:5555 install program.apk
577 KB/s (1673947 bytes in 2.832s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/program.apk
Success
```

I have waited for up to 5 minutes, but nothing happens.

How can I make `adb -d` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try help sometimes with console commands. -d flag works only with usb devices:

```
zaytzev@piec-ubu:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools$ ./adb --help
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31

-d        - directs command to the only connected USB device
          returns an error if more than one USB device is present.
```

Comment: I've read the help, but overread that damn 3 letters. Thank you!

Comment: The Flag -e (which is for single emulator, according to the help) seems to work with a network connected device.